# CartThrob 2.6.1 and EE 2.7.3 || Guest Add to Cart

Tags: cartthrob, guest

I'm having a couple of issues with CartThrob 2.6.1 and ExpressionEngine 2.7.3. Are there any known issues with Guest Checkout with these versions?

Here's the setup:

`User Must Be Logged In?` NO

`Logged Out Member ID:` 383 (which relates to a guest member ID)

`Use Fingerprinting For Sessions?` NO (also tried all the other options too)

---

If I'm logged in as a Super Admin then I can add items to my cart, but guests cannot.

I did notice that the `member_id` field in the Database wasn't being set to `383` either. Another weird item is that `Show Debug Info (when using debug_info tag)` is set to `Show to SuperAdmins only` and the use of the debug tag in my templates shows for everyone!

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, running EEP 2.7.0, so annoying! Did you discover a fix for it?

Comment: Upgrading both EE and CT fixed the guest checkout issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading both EE and CT fixed the guest checkout issues.